# how to split the array in php and pass to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array came from php file.

```
"[{\"username\":\"a.villar026\",\"fullname\":\"Alexis Abulencia Villar\"}]"
```

This is the array setting in the php file retrieved in the MYSQL table. then I want to get the value of username and fullname of the array but when i return it as a javascript variable, the result is `undefined`.

I tried the codes below:

```
var user = JSON.stringify(msg.username);
var name = JSON.stringify(msg.fullname);

var user = JSON.stringify(msg[0]['username']);
var name = JSON.stringify(msg[0]['fullname']);

var user = JSON.stringify(msg[0]); //this returns only an character ({) or {[}
var name = JSON.stringify(msg[1]); //this returns only an character ({) or {[}
```

my question is, how can i possibly set the value of a variable in javascript using php array.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#logout").click(function(){

        });
    getUser();
 });

    function getUser(){
    var user ='';
    var session ='';
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'../bench/php/session.php',
                data:'',
                success:function(msg){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                     user = JSON.stringify(msg.username);

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                }, error: function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
    }
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   $temparray = array();

      $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username,fullname from user where username = '$user_check'");

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($row > 0 ){         
                array_push($temparray, $row); //save your data into array
        }

       echo json_encode($temparray);

       if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
          header("location:index.html");
       }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i possibly set the value of a variable in javascript using php array.

```js
let response = "[{\"username\":\"a.villar026\",\"fullname\":\"Alexis Abulencia Villar\"}]"
let data = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(data)
data[0].username = "something"
console.log(data)
```